# Objective-C edit NSString programmatically

Tags: objective-c

I'm loading data from XML to my news string. The data looks like this: "Some new, more news, news/other language news, more news on other language". How can I remove everything after "/" so the string looks like this: "Some new, more news, news"?

Thanks!

Comment: Please consider at least skimming through the documentation (or looking for answers on this site) before asking something as basic as this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `componentsSeparatedByString:` and get the first element of the array like this:

```
NSString *string = @"foo/bar";
NSString *foo = [[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] firstObject];
```

If you are unsure whether or not a `/` character is contained in the string, check the return value of `componentsSeparatedByString:`.

Comment: I did, but I didn't manage to find answere

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
NSString *stringXML = @"Some new, more news, news/other language news, more news on other language";
NSRange range = [stringXML rangeOfString:@"/"];
NSLog(@"%@", [stringXML substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, range.location)]);
```

Comment: This is the better answer. Using `componentsSeparatedByString` is overkill and far less efficient.